# VSCode formatting extension (python) which places the function arguments into a column

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, formatting

I was wondering if anyone knows about an extension which basically formats the functions/methods in the file so that the function arguments are stacked into a column.

Here is what I mean; I am looking for an extension that takes a "raw" function like so

```
def super_function(arg,arg,arg,arg,arg,arg):
    # Solves the Navier-Stokes equations in O(n).
    return True
```

and formats it so that the function argument are stacked in a column:

```
def super_function(arg,
                   arg,
                   arg,
                   arg,
                   arg,
                   arg):
    # Solves the Navier-Stokes equations in O(n).
    return True
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PEP8 and almost all Python code-styles don't force arguments to be stacked in column.

PEP8 official examples:

```
# Add 4 spaces (an extra level of indentation) to distinguish arguments from the rest.
def long_function_name(
        var_one, var_two, var_three,
        var_four):
    print(var_one)


# Further indentation required as indentation is not distinguishable.
def long_function_name(
    var_one, var_two, var_three,
    var_four):
    print(var_one)
```

So no, 99% that you will not find a tool in VS Code to do it for you (at least I can't find it in most popular Python extensions). But you can use multiple selections for it:

- Select the first comma in your arguments line
- Press <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> until the last comma in the line
- Press  to set all selections to the places after commas
- Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to add EOLs after each comma
- Add tabulations/spaces to justify your code

Note, that this method will add EOLs even in lists/tuples in arguments, so be careful!